# Pandas Add Column Index Level to Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

Given the following data frame:

```
d2=pd.DataFrame({'Item':['y','y','z','x'],
                'other':['aa','bb','cc','dd']})
d2

    Item    other
0   y       aa
1   y       bb
2   z       cc
3   x       dd
```

I'd like to add a column index level 1 under the existing one (I think) because I want to join this data frame to another that is a multi-index.
I don't want to alter the other data frame because I have already written a lot of code assuming its current structure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can add parameter `append=True` to [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (d2.set_index('Item', append=True))
       other
  Item      
0 y       aa
1 y       bb
2 z       cc
3 x       dd
```